# Uncaught Error:classes are not declared in sencha touch

Tags: javascript, extjs, sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2

I face following problem in sencha touch.

> (1)Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token : (in Morecard1.js line no.:5)
>
> (2)Uncaught Error: The following classes are not declared even if their files have been loaded: 'chat.view.Morecard1'. Please check the source code of their corresponding files for possible typos: 'app/view/Morecard1.js

`app.js:`

```
    Ext.Loader.setConfig({

});

Ext.application({
    views: [
        'Home',
        'Morecard1',
        'grouplist',
        'Inner1'
    ],
    stores:[
        'MyStore'
    ],
    models:[
        'MyModel'
    ],
    name: 'chat',

    launch: function() {

        Ext.create('chat.view.Home', {fullscreen: true});
    }

});
```

`Morecard1.js:`

```
Ext.define('chat.view.Morecard1', {
    extend: 'Ext.NavigationView',
    xtype:'Morecard1',
    config: {
        items: [xtype:'Inner1'],
    }
});
```

`Inner1.js:`

```
Ext.define('chat.view.Inner1',{
 
    extend:'Ext.Panel',
 
    xtype:'Inner1',
 
    requires:['Ext.dataview.List','Ext.data.Store'],
 
    config:{
 
        title:'My List',
 
        layout:'fit',
 
        items:[
 
        {
 
             xtype:'list',
 
             store:'MyStore',
 
             itemTpl:'<b>{name}<b>'
 
        }
 
        ]
 
    }
 
});
```

so what is the problem? I try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18463690/sencha-touch-error-the-following-classes-are-not-declared-even-if-their-files) but no success.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: these type of error only comes when u missout any comma or js files declared in ext.application are not loaded..

Comment: In the app.js, you should add stores as well.

Comment: i add store and model, please see edited quetion.but still i face this error.

Comment: @codebreaker, all files are loaded, i checked it in  console.

Comment: if ur still getting the first error it means u have missed out any comma in the js files ur coding into look into the code this tedius process..gud luck

Comment: i found the problem and solve it (saw my answer),but no idea why it is happen?

Answer (score 0):

I change `Morecard1.js` file and problem solved.

```
Ext.define('chat.view.Morecard1', {
  extend: 'Ext.NavigationView',
  xtype:'Morecard1',
  config: {
      items: [
        {
          xtype:'Inner1'
        }
      ]
  }
});
```

here i added `{}` braces in items. actually i refer [first-steps-in-sencha-touch](http://www.sitepoint.com/first-steps-in-sencha-touch/) tutorial and there is no braces for this line.and when i put the braces,the error is gone but i have no idea why it is happen?

Comment: i said u  there might be some comma, or syntax not correct u have forgotten the braces...